# How to increase the size of the max track of a UISlider?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uislider

I would like to add a UISlider with a size different from min to max.

Here is an example of what I need :

[image]

I've tried to play with some methods like :

```
- (CGRect)minimumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)maximumValueImageRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)trackRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds;
- (CGRect)thumbRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds trackRect:(CGRect)rect value:(float)value;
```

But I can't manage to get it work...
Any suggestion or maybe link on how do you achieve that ?

Comment: `trackRectForBounds` is the way. Why don't you show us some code?

Comment: nothing works properly, i don't think it will help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass UISlider. If you are creating UISlider at run time you should use `initWithFrame` otherwise `initWithCoder`.

```
@implementation slider

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // At certain point images swap, that is why you need images fit to your UISlider size.
        UIImage *sliderLeftImg = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"slider2"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 10 topCapHeight: 0];
        UIImage *sliderRightImg = [[UIImage imageNamed: @"slider"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: 10 topCapHeight: 0];
        [self setMinimumTrackImage: sliderLeftImg forState: UIControlStateNormal];
        [self setMaximumTrackImage: sliderRightImg forState: UIControlStateNormal];

    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

The sample images I draw loops sloppy, you need better ones.

[UISlider Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISlider_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

[image]
[image]

Final Result:

[image]

Comment: Omg it could not be as simple as that... What do look like your images "slider" and "slider2" ? Is it the two above the final results ?

Comment: @kl94 both images (slider and slider2) attached to post.

Comment: I thought stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you an idea why it doesn't work with IB ? (event without using stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth: ). Setting -[setMinimumTrackImage:] and -[setMaximumTrackImage:] "programmatically" did the job. But on IB, it doesn't appear to work. Have you an idea ?

Comment: I have created subclass of the UISlider, added the code which I wrote in the post then put a UISlider on the UIViewController, selected it then on IB / Identity Inspector / Custom class / Class and typed my custom class name there. that is it.

Comment: Yeah of course, but I mean without subclass ? Settings Min/Max Images appears to not work as the same as programmatically.

Comment: I am sorry my bad understanding. Never tried that the other way.